# Can´t connect to proxies

Tags: python, proxies

I try do use proxies for people also ask but it does not work.

```
import people_also_ask
import people_also_ask.request.session


username = "user"
password = "123456"
proxy = "pr.oxylabs.io:7777"

people_also_ask.request.session.set_proxies(
    (
        'http://{username}:{password}@{proxy}'
    )
)


a = people_also_ask.get_related_questions("coffee")

print (a)
```

I know this proxy provider work but i always get an error
In my test Code I add the proxies like them.

```
##OxylabDaten########
username = "user"
password = "123456"
proxy = "pr.oxylabs.io:7777"

##Proxies#####

proxies = {
      'http': f'http://{username}:{password}@{proxy}',
      'https': f'http://{username}:{password}@{proxy}'
    }

r = requests.get(googlelink, headers=headers, proxies = proxies, verify=False) #r = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=snap+7&num=100',headers=headers,)
```

Does anyone know how can I run people also ask with proxies and without errors.

This is the error message.

> people_also_ask.exceptions.RequestError:
> ('https://www.google.com/search', {'q': 'coffee', 'gl': 'us'},
> {'https': 'http://t'}, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in
> _new_conn\n    conn = connection.create_connection(\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73,
> in create_connection\n    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port,
> family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py",
> line 953, in getaddrinfo\n    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host,
> port, family, type, proto, flags):\nsocket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name
> or service not known\n\nDuring handling of the above exception,
> another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 696, in urlopen\n    self._prepare_proxy(conn)\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 966,
> in _prepare_proxy\n    conn.connect()\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in
> connect\n    conn = self._new_conn()\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in
> _new_conn\n    raise NewConnectionError(\nurllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
> <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5025312190>: Failed
> to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not
> known\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in
> send\n    resp = conn.urlopen(\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755,
> in urlopen\n    retries = retries.increment(\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in
> increment\n    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or
> ResponseError(cause))\nurllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /search?q=coffee&gl=us (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7f5025312190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
> or service not known')))\n\nDuring handling of the above exception,
> another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/people_also_ask/request/session.py",
> line 86, in get\n    response = SESSION.get(\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in
> get\n    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in
> request\n    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in
> send\n    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)\n  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in
> send\n    raise ProxyError(e,
> request=request)\nrequests.exceptions.ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /search?q=coffee&gl=us (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7f5025312190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
> or service not known')))\n')

I tried it with free proxy providers.